# Codeigniter 404 Page Not Found in Signup form

Tags: php

I just created my sign up form with email verification but it's giving me error "`404 Page Not Found`" when I click on Sign up button?
Here is my view named as sign_up:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Registeration</title>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/form-elements.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/style.css">

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Top menu -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-no-bg" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-navbar-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Bootstrap Registration Form Template</a>-->
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-navbar-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <span class="li-text">
                                Put some information
                            </span> 
                            <!--<a href="#"><strong>links</strong></a> -->
                            <span class="li-text">
                                here to get access: 
                            </span> 
                            <span class="li-social">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> 
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- Top content -->
        <div class="top-content">

            <div class="inner-bg">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-7 text">
                            <h1><strong>Register</strong> Here</h1>
                            <div class="description">
                                <div class="row">

</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="top-big-link">
                                <!--<a class="btn btn-link-1" href="#">Button 1</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-link-2" href="#">Button 2</a>-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 form-box">
                            <div class="form-top">
                                <div class="form-top-left">
                                    <h3>Sign up now</h3>
                                    <p>Fill in the form below to get instant access:</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-top-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                <?php $attributes = array("name" => "registrationform");
                echo form_open("Register/reg", $attributes);?>
                                <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="registration-form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="form-first-name">Full Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="name"  value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" placeholder="Full Name..." class="form-first-name form-control" id="name" required>
                                         <?php echo form_error('name'); ?></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Email</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="email"  value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" placeholder="Email..." class="form-email form-control" id="email" required>
                                         <span class="text-danger">
                                          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="form-last-name">Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-last-name form-control" id="password" required>
                                      <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span> 
                                    </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="form-last-name">Confirm Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Confirm Password..." class="form-last-name form-control" id="cpassword" required>
                                         <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('cpassword'); ?></span> 
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign me up!</button>
                                     <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel!</button>
                               <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                               <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/retina-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

        <!--[if lt IE 10]>
            <script src="assets/js/placeholder.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </body>

</html>
```

here is controller named as Register:

```
   <?php
class Register extends CI_Controller
{

    function index()
    {
        $this->reg();

    }

    function reg()
    {
        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Full Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[cpassword]|md5');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required');
        $this->load->view('Seller/login');
        //validate form input
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // fails
            $this->load->view('sign_up');
        }
        else
        {
            //insert the user registration details into database
            $data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );

            // insert form data into database
            if ($this->Seller_model->insertUser($data))
            {
                // send email
                if ($this->Seller_model->sendEmail($this->input->post('email')))
                {
                    // successfully sent mail
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Successfully Registered! Please confirm the mail sent to your Email-ID!!!</div>');
                    redirect('Register/reg');
                }
                else
                {
                    // error
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                    redirect('Register/reg');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                redirect('Register/reg');
            }
        }
    }

    function verify($hash=NULL)
    {
        if ($this->Seller_model->verifyEmailID($hash))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('verify_msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your Email Address is successfully verified! Please login to access your account!</div>');
            redirect('Register/reg');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('verify_msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Sorry! There is error verifying your Email Address!</div>');
            redirect('Register/reg');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

here is model named Seller_model:

```
  <?php
class Admin_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //insert into user table
    function insertUser($data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    }

    //send verification email to user's email id
    function sendEmail($to_email)
    {
        $from_email = 'team@abc.com'; //change this to yours
        $subject = 'Verify Your Email Address';
        $message = 'Dear User,<br /><br />Please click on the below activation link to verify your email address.<br /><br /> anywebsite/user/verify/' . md5($to_email) . '<br /><br /><br />Thanks<br />` `Mydomain Team';

        //configure email settings
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.mydomain.com'; //smtp host name
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465'; //smtp port number
        $config['smtp_user'] = $from_email;
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '********'; //$from_email password
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
        $this->email->initialize($config);

        //send mail
        $this->email->from($from_email, 'Mydomain');
        $this->email->to($to_email);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        return $this->email->send();
    }

    //activate user account
    function verifyEmailID($key)
    {
        $data = array('status' => 1);
        $this->db->where('md5(email)', $key);
        return $this->db->update('user', $data);
    }
    }?>
```

Here is routes:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI ROUTING
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you re-map URI requests to specific controller functions.
|
| Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string
| and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a
| URL normally follow this pattern:
|
|   example.com/class/method/id/
|
| In some instances, however, you may want to remap this relationship
| so that a different class/function is called than the one
| corresponding to the URL.
|
| Please see the user guide for complete details:
|
|   https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RESERVED ROUTES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| There are three reserved routes:
|
|   $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
|
| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
| would be loaded.
|
|   $route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
|
| This route will tell the Router which controller/method to use if those
| provided in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.
|
|   $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
|
| This is not exactly a route, but allows you to automatically route
| controller and method names that contain dashes. '-' isn't a valid
| class or method name character, so it requires translation.
| When you set this option to TRUE, it will replace ALL dashes in the
| controller and method URI segments.
|
| Examples: my-controller/index -> my_controller/index
|       my-controller/my-method -> my_controller/my_method
*/
$route['default_controller'] = 'Seller';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Please include your routes or routing table. A 404 page is usually a sign that the URL you are accessing is incorrect. Also, search StackOverflow as many users have had this same issue.

Comment: #Aaron I have added routes.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you don't use the mod_rewrite so you must create urls in this way `index.php?/Register/reg`. Read about mod_rewrite if you use apache and how to make pretty urls.